# Checking a word against a dictionary

Tags: vb.net, string-comparison

I want a way of checking a word against a dictionary (if at all possible). If not possible against a dictionary then check against a list of words (txt or excel sheet).

```
Dim word As String

Console.WriteLine("Enter a message: ")
word = Console.ReadLine()

' If word <> dictionary Then
' Console.WriteLine("word in the dictionary")
' End If
```

Comment: A dictionary is essentially a list of words. You should compose such a dictionary and check if the word is _contained_ in that list of words.

Comment: Are you serious? lol you have just repeated what I asked in my question. Anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: No, I'm trying to make you realize that a dictionary is the same as list of distinct words in this context and how you would normally check if a list contains the entry you seek. If you do not simplify a problem to the basics, then it will be hard to implement a solution. I was only trying to help.

Comment: Dictionary stores key-value pairs. From your question, I find it that you store only a list of words. For this you can use a `HashSet<String>`. It will store only the words and you can check using the `Contains` function. It will remove the memory overhead of storing the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to know if the word is in the dictionary's key or value?

```
If dictionary.ContainsKey(word) Then
    Console.WriteLine("Word in Dictionary-Key")
End If
If dictionary.ContainsValue(word) Then
    Console.WriteLine("Word in Dictionary-Value")
End If
```

(assuming that the `Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)` is a `Dictionary(Of String, String)`)

`ContainsKey` is the most efficient approach. If you even want to know if it's part of a key or value you have to use a loop or Linq (which also uses loops internally):

```
If dictionary.Keys.Any(Function(k) k.Contains(word)) Then
    Console.WriteLine("Part of word in Dictionary-Key was word")
End If
If dictionary.Values.Any(Function(k) k.Contains(word)) Then
    Console.WriteLine("Part of word in Dictionary-Value was word")
End If
```